# Put social Icons next to body field ($content['body'])

Tags: theming

I want to align my social icons vertically next to the body field, in my node.tpl.php file the body is included in the $content with everything else. The social icons sit a few lines above and look like this in my node.tpl.php file:

```
<div class="main-node-social-share">
  <?php print render($main_node_social_share);?>
</div>
```

How can i get $main_node_social_share to render right before the $content['body'] field?

```
// We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
hide($content['comments']);
hide($content['links']);
print render($content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this in custom module and see it helps.

```
function modulename_page_alter(&$page) {
  $social=array(
    '#markup'=>'<div id="social"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_square-128.png"></div>',
  );
  array_unshift($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][1],$social);

}
```

Comment: Although this didn't exactly work in my situation it is the  right solution.  Thanks